# .NET Core 3.1 Windows Forms Designer Bug?

Tags: winforms, .net-core, radio-button

I've created a .NET Core 3.1 Windows Forms app and am trying to add a RadioButton inside a Panel inside a TabPage using the designer but it won't let me. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

In addition, I cannot reposition the Panel using the mouse, only cursor keys.

I can do this just fine in a .NET 4.7.2 app.

Answer (score 1):

You can double click to user control on components panel.
It will be added to 0,0 coordinate on Windows form.

Comment: That seems to work, but I cannot reposition the Panel or RadioButton with the mouse.